# Java Swing, setPage() does not change the JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, events, jeditorpane

I have two classes, one for the buttons, text field and action listeners for the buttons, and one containing the `JEditorPane` and the methods the action listeners call.

The problem I am having is with the `setPage` method not actually setting the page, so the `JEditorPane` is not updated.

The scenario is as follows:

- I have a button that is clicked to search for a web page
- When clicked the action listener triggers and calls `visitPage` in my `WebBrowserPane` class passing the URL from the text box
- the `visitPage` method takes this URL and calls `setPage(url)`

I would expect this to change the JEditorPane, but it doesn't. I have a working version but I am splitting the functionality and interface into different classes.

I have researched before, finding no real answers except using:

```
Document doc = jep.getDocument(); 

doc.putProperty(Document.StreamDescriptionProperty, null);
```

To summarize my problem is that the `setPage(url)` doesn't seem to change the `JEditorPane`. The following is the code for a example of the problem

### `ToolBar`

```
public class ToolBar {

    private JToolBar toolBar;
    private JTextField field;
    private JButton go;
    private Editor editor = new Editor();
    
    ToolBar() {
        toolBar = new JToolBar();
        
        field = new JTextField(50);
        toolBar.add(field);

        go = new JButton("Go");
        toolBar.add(go);
        
        go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    editor.visitPage(new URL(field.getText()));
                } catch(MalformedURLException murle) {
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        });
    }

    public JToolBar getToolBar() {
        return toolBar;
    }
}
```

### `Editor`

```
public class Editor {

    private JEditorPane jep;
    private JScrollPane jsp;
    
    private static final int EDITOR_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int EDITOR_HEIGHT = 500;
    
    Editor() {
        jep = new JEditorPane();
        jep.setEditable(false);
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jep);
        jep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EDITOR_WIDTH,EDITOR_HEIGHT));
        
        
    }
    
    public void visitPage(URL url) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Going to: "+url);
            jep.setPage(url);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ioe);
        }
    }
    
    public JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {
        return jsp;
    }
}
```

### `Window`

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    private JPanel topPanel;
    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    Editor editor = new Editor();

    Window() {
        super("Web Browser");
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(editor.getJScrollPane());

        topPanel.add(toolBar.getToolBar());

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window webBrowser = new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Do I need to include some code from my classes?"* No, not 'some code' not 'all the code', but.. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `public class ToolBar { ..  private Editor editor = new Editor();` This creates an instance of an `Editor` that is **entirely separate** to the instance that is displayed in the `Window`. Calling the page to change the URL will have no visible effect since this instance of the editor is never displayed on anything. To work it requires a reference to the editor that is in the `Window` class, or access to a method that does have that access.